# How to include smart italics within BibTex entries

Tags: bibtex

I would like to use italics within BibTeX entries to indicate the title of an artwork, as is traditional in some scholarly publications.  The problem is that `{\it }` and `{\em }` are processed awkwardly in the .sty files I use.  Below is a kludged way to include *Portrait of Cardinal Niccolo Albergati* within the .bib entry.

Is there any elegant and simple way to avoid all the added characters and forced spacing here?

For instance, if I use the obvious `{\em Portrait of Cardinal Niccol\'o Albergati}` or `{\em {P}ortrait of {C}ardinal {N}iccol\'o {A}lbergati}` or `{\it Portrait of Cardinal Niccol\'o Albergati}` I do not get the needed upper-case letters.

```
@ARTICLE{DuarteStork:10,
       AUTHOR = "Marco Duarte and David G. Stork",
        TITLE = "Image contour fidelity analysis of mechanically aided enlargements of {J}an van {E}yck\rq s ${P}$\hspace{-0.1mm}{\em ortrait of} ${C}$\hspace{-0.2mm}{\em ardinal} ${N}$\hspace{-0.2mm}{\em iccol\`o} ${A}$\hspace{-0.2mm}{\em lbergati}",
      JOURNAL = "Leonardo",
       VOLUME = "43",
       NUMBER = "1",
        PAGES = "43--50",
         YEAR = "2010"
}
```

I'm using ieee.sty and ieee.bst.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What bibliography style are you using?

Comment: Which bibliography style(s) do you use? What, specifically, does "awkward  processing" mean? Have you tried `title = "Image contour fidelity analysis of mechanically aided enlargements of {Jan van Eyck's} {{\em Portrait of Cardinal Niccol{\\`o} Albergati}}",`? If `{{\em ...}}` doesn't work for you, have you tried `{\textit{...}}`?

Comment: Regarding your update: Did you mean to say that you use the `ieeetr` style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing strange with this input:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{DuarteStork:10,
  AUTHOR = "Marco Duarte and David G. Stork",
   TITLE = "Image contour fidelity analysis of mechanically aided
            enlargements of {Jan} van {Eyck's} \emph{Portrait of
            Cardinal Niccol\`o Albergati}",
 JOURNAL = "Leonardo",
  VOLUME = "43",
  NUMBER = "1",
   PAGES = "43--50",
    YEAR = "2010"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\cite{DuarteStork:10}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is just to keep the example self-contained.

[image]

If I change the style to `amsplain`, which italicizes article titles, I get

[image]

where you see that “smart” emphasis is used.

Comment: Thanks.  Putting `\emph` *outside* the artwork title works fine with ieee.sty and ieee.bst.  Wonderful.